# ampy no longer connecting

Tags: esptool

I had `ampy` working for a while. It was intermittent after that, and now it doesn't work most of the time. I'm able to run `esptool.py --port COM3 flash_id` and `esptool.py --port COM3 chip_id`, but when I try to run `ampy --port COM3 ls` or `ampy --port COM3 run test.py` it just hangs.

I've tried:

- Restarting computer
- Shutting down computer
- Different USB ports
- Different ESP32s and ESP8266s

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that different devices in the same family need to be flashed differently. I was flashing MicroPython with ESP-Now on a Wemos D1 Mini using:

```
esptool.py --chip esp8266 --port COM11 write_flash -z 0x1000 C:\Users\Main\Downloads\firmware-esp8266-GENERIC.bin
```

and it should have been:

```
esptool.py --port COM11 --baud 1000000 write_flash --flash_size=4MB -fm dio 0 C:\Users\Main\Downloads\firmware-esp8266-GENERIC.bin
```